# I need help to understand how to access information from Combinations

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

For a school project, I have to be able to figure out how to see if every array in a combination is in ascending order. However, I have no idea how to access the information at a certain point in the combination.
Heres my Code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < comboObjects.length; i++) {
  if (comboObjects[i] (are in accending order)) {

  }
}
```

Comment: What does a combination look like? Please give an example of what the input data might look like and what the output would be

Comment: what's the precise type of comboObjects?